# Removing duplicates in a playlist in Traktor

Tags: windows-7, traktor

My playlist in Traktor contains duplicate tracks:

[image]

Is there any way to remove all duplicates at once?

I use Traktor Pro 2.6.5 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The best way would be to use iTunes' function for removing duplicates - assuming that you are loading the same collection in both Traktor and iTunes :-)

Answer (score 4):

In the left-hand list of playlists right click on the playlist you wish to de-duplicate and click `Remove Duplicates from Playlist`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: @Sean, would you like to show this option on screenshot? I have never seen it from early releases of Traktor until Traktor 2.10. Thank you!